# Get the old version of stored procedure code in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

We have modified one of our stored procedures code and accidentally committed it in production DB also. Now we need the older version of the code. Is there any way to get the old version of a stored procedure from the DB? We didn't take any backup of the code. Please help.

Comment: Restore it from the backup of the database.

Comment: there is no versions within sql server for stored procedure and hence you cannot get an older version of procedure from a db. you should use a source control for such purposes

Comment: Are you using any config management tool? If so, you can restore from that

Comment: Not possible, unless you have taken full backup of your db.

Comment: You must have moved it to Production using some ticket ..get it from there  or retrieve it from soucre control system..

Comment: To avoid such problems in future try to implement this https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2085/sql-server-ddl-triggers-to-track-all-database-changes/. It is a short term fix if you don't have super duper source control system's.

Answer (score 3):

To answer you directly.

You cannot get back the old version of the sp , if it is already executed in production, unless you have a backup or you have a customize trigger that logs all execution of sp.

This happens to my team before, that's why we created a trigger that logs all execution. or you can use SQL source control.

The only thing that you can do now is **data fix** in production.

Comment: Source control is your best friend. Triggers should be use with parsimony